# SOLR text analyzer for find and order documents by similarity

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm trying to write text analyzer for finding and order similar documents to user entered text, but I can't achieve required result.

Here is what I want achieve:

- Apply tokenizer and filters to document name field which parse text to tokens. I used this for index analyzer:

  ```
  <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15"/>
  <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>`
  ```
- Next I want create analyzer for query which split user input text into tokens by space and compares these tokens separately with AND operator between comparisons.
- After that return documents which match token of each entered word ordered by similarity
- With similarity I mean `how many tokens of user entered word contains stored documents`

For instance:

- If user enter `hel` he will find documents which contains `hell`, `helium`, `hello world`, ...
- When user add another words I want refine results, and returns documents which contains token for each entered word. So when user enter `helo word` I need boost document text `hello world` because this document match more tokens like `helium` or `hell`.

Can you tell me what text analyzer should looks like to achieve my search goals? I'm just starting with Solr so I will be happy for any advice. Thank you.

Comment: The analyzer does not affect scoring - only the number of matching tokens (and length of field, etc.) does. The behaviour you're asking for is the default behaviour (with additional weights depending on how unique the terms are across the document)  - the more tokens that match, the higher the score of the document will be. You can append `debug=all` to your query to see how the score is being calculated.

Comment: @MatsLindh thank you, is possible also limit result by match score to ensure user will not see any nonsenses? For instance if user enter `hldsdd wrldd` there will be no results. I want display only reasonable results.

Comment: There is no way to quantify "reasonable results". If it's a hit, it's a reasonable hit. If you don't want specific words to give hits, don't make your analysis chain generate the tokens that when compared indicates a hit. For ngram tokenizers or filters you usually only want to apply them when indexing, not when querying (.. which would give waaaay too wide results).

Comment: @MatsLindh just for clarification, I would have AND between user entered words, it means when user multiple words I want match each word, and if NO match in both so show no result. For instance user enters `helo world` and I will show only `Hello world` and not `Hell` because hell does't match any token from world.

Comment: If you have indexed `Hello World`, `helo world` shouldn't give a hit either (.. unless you have an ngram filter/tokenizer on both sides, which will give you weird hits). But yes, your assumption otherwise is correct. The value just `Hell` indexed will not give a hit when searching for `helo world` with `q.op=AND`.

Comment: @MatsLindh I enter new question for last question here, because I tried op and not works for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58059007/refine-search-results-for-more-words-in-solr