# Refine search results for more words in SOLR

Tags: solr

I want achieve refine search results when user enter more words by using AND operator between token compassion results.

I tried set `qo=AND` but doesn't work and return results which contains only one of entered words.

For instance I using for field searching analyzer like this:

```
<fieldType name="serch_text" class="solr.TextField">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

so for query `searching:(hel world)` I want apply analyzer for each word and do AND between results. In practice I expecting something like this:

(hel **compare to** h, he, hel, hell, hello) **AND** (world **compare to** w, wo, ...)

and return results where there are matching both.

Comment: The argument is `q.op=AND`. The analysis page will also tell you which tokens are being generated on each side, so that output will tell you why both inputs are being hit. In general, ngramfilters when both indexing and querying will give you weird results (i.e. `hell` queried will give a hit against `hole`, since both will have generated the token `h`)

Comment: @MatsLindh yes you right, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is `q.op=AND`.

The analysis page will also tell you which tokens are being generated on each side, so that output will tell you why both inputs are being hit.

In general, NGram filters (and tokenizer) when both indexing and querying will give you weird results (i.e. hell queried will give a hit against hole, since both will have generated the token h)

Usually you'll only want to ngram when you're indexing (to get autocomplete/start of word functionality).